# Can I send ascii input through a dualshock 3

Tags: telnet, ascii

is it possible to send ascii input to a computer through a dualshock 3? I'm trying to play a telnet game called mtrek through a terminal with a controller.

Comment: If you run `xev` and then press buttons on the controller (without moving the mouse/keyboard) do you get any output?

Comment: Nope, none of the results update :(

Comment: How do you currently have the controller set up?

Comment: I have a shell script script that runs this command      sudo xboxdrv -d